# select * from <tablename> not using any key

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.1 version in Windows 2008 server. When I execute below queries:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename;
```

It is taking too much time for fetching all the results in that table. This query is listed in the slow query log too while this table has primary key as well as few more index. 
I execute below query to check the execution plan:

```
explain extended select * from tablename;
```

I found below information:

```
id=1
select_type=SIMPLE
table=tablename
possible_keys=null
key=null
key_len=null
ref=null
rows=85151
Extra=blank
```

I thought that it query should use at least primary key by default. Again, I executed below query and found that filtered column has value=100.0

```
explain extended select * from tablenmae;
```

Is there any specific reason about why query is not utilizing key?

Comment: Why should it use a "key"? You want *everything* from the table, so there is no way using an index (which I think you mean with "key") will speed up anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting all rows from the table. This is why the whole table (all rows) needs to be scanned.

A key (or index) is only used if you narrow your search (using where). An index is used in that case to pre-select the rows which you want to have without having to actually scan the whole table for the given criteria.

If you don't need to access all the rows at once, try limiting the returned rows using LIMIT.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 100;
```

If you want the next 100 rows, use

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 100,100;
```

and so on.

Other than that approach (referred to as "paging"), there is not much you can do to speed up this query (other than get a faster machine, more RAM, a faster disk, better network if the DMBS is accessed remotely).

If you need to do some processing, consider moving logic (such as filtering) to the DBMS. This can be achieved using the `WHERE` portion of a query.

Comment: How much it helps if I add columns name in place of *?

Comment: Nothing, if you put all column names, I fear.
If you put some (not all) column names, technically, you would get a minimal improvement, but only because the DBMS does have to move less data over the connection. But this effect is more of a theoretical nature. 

It's iterating through all of the table what's most expensive here.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it use a key, when there is no filter, nor order? - there's going to be no approach, in this single table query, where a table scan is not going to be at least as fast.

To solve your performance issue, perhaps you have client side processing that could be passed tot he server (after all, you're not really showing 85,151 rows to the end user at once, are you?) - or get a faster disk...